# Creating custom controller which extends Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, sapui5

I am creating custom controller which extends Dialog. I want default function of Dialog thats why I write

```
renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {         
        sap.ui.commons.DialogRenderer.render(oRm, oControl);
            oRm.write("Testing Text in Dialog box");
    },
```

also I want to add some text and some controls in that dialog box
but whenever I create object of my custom controller that time I get dialog box including the next text"Testing text in dialog box". I was unable to find out how to write the code. Above code is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sap.ui.commons.Dialog.extend("test.dialog", {  

metadata : {},


init: function() {

    if (sap.ui.commons.Dialog.prototype.init) {             
        sap.ui.commons.Dialog.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    var oLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
        text : "Testing Text in Dialog box"
    });
    this.addContent(oLabel);
  },

renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
    sap.ui.commons.DialogRenderer.render(oRm, oControl);
   }
});
```